# Type Text Directly On A Bitmap Image at Mouse Position

Tags: vb.net, charts, graphics, data-visualization

I am trying to write (type) directly onto a bitmap.  I need to be able to type at the mouse position, so where ever on the screen i click the mouse, I can start typing text with the keyboard.

Here is a working VS 2017 VB Win Form code that will print "Hello World" at the mousedown position.  But it only works with predetermined text. I would like to be able to just type at that spot.  I feel I am so close, just can't get it to work.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

Public Class Form1

    Dim WithEvents Chart1 As New Chart
    Private Structure TextPoints
        Dim MPos As Point
        Dim Txt As String
    End Structure
    Private TextList As New List(Of TextPoints)
    Private TempPoint As Point
    Private FirstPoint As Point
    Dim xcnt As Integer = -1
    Dim ycnt As Integer = -1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.Size = New Size(1100, 700)
        Me.Location = New Point(10, 10)
        MakeBackImage()
        With Chart1
            .Name = "Chart1"
            .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(40, 40)
            .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(1010, 610)
            .BackImage = "BackImg.jpg"
            .Parent = Me
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub Chart1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object,
                                 ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) _
                                 Handles Chart1.MouseDown
        FirstPoint = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
        TempPoint = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
        Me.Refresh()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Chart1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object,
                           ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) _
                           Handles Chart1.MouseUp
        Dim T As New TextPoints With {
            .MPos = TempPoint,
            .Txt = "Hello World"}
        TextList.Add(T)
        Me.Refresh()
    End Sub

    Private Sub MakeBackImage()
        Dim x, y As Integer
        Dim img As Image = New Bitmap(1020, 620)
        Dim graphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img)
        graphics.Clear(Drawing.Color.White)
        For x = 0 To 1000 Step 20
            graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, x, 0, x, 600)
            xcnt += 1
        Next
        For y = 0 To 600 Step 20
            ycnt += 1
            graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, y, 1000, y)
        Next
        img.Save("BackImg.jpg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Chart1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object,
                             ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) _
                             Handles Chart1.Paint
        Dim drawString As String = "Hello World"
        Dim drawFont As New Font("Arial", 14)
        Dim drawBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
        For Each t As TextPoints In TextList
            e.Graphics.DrawString(t.Txt, drawFont,
                                  drawBrush, t.MPos.X, t.MPos.Y)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

This is a simplified code. Actually, the background image is only created once, but I added code to dynamically create it here to make the demo better.

Comment: why can't you type into a transparent textbox?

Comment: You need to handle the appropriate keyboard events to determine what characters to draw.

Comment: There is no transparent property for a textbox.